# Writing unit tests for Solr plugin using JUnit4, including creating collections

Tags: junit, solr, junit4, solrj, solrcloud

I wrote a plugin for Solr which contains new stream expressions.
Now, I'm trying to understand what is the best way to write them unit tests:
Unit tests which need to include creation of collections in Solr, so I will be able to check if my new stream expressions return me the right data they suppose.

I saw over the web that there is a class called "SolrTestCaseJ4", but I didn't find how to use it for creating new collections in Solr and add them data and so on...

Can you please recommend me which class may I use for that purpose or any other way to test my new classes?

BTW, we are using Solr 7.1 in cloud mode and JUnit4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I found a better class, which simplifies everything and implements more functionality than `MiniSolrCloudCluster` (actually it contains `MiniSolrCloudCluster` inside it as a member).

This class called `SolrCloudTestCase`, and as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/test/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/io/stream/StreamExpressionTest.java#L79), even Solr's source code uses it in their own unit tests.

Answer (score 5):

you could use [MiniSolrCloudCluster](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/b091934f9e98568b848d0584a1145c8e514cbd21/solr/test-framework/src/java/org/apache/solr/cloud/MiniSolrCloudCluster.java#L63)

Here is an example how to create collections (all for unit test):

https://github.com/lucidworks/solr-hadoop-common/blob/159cce044c1907e646c2644083096150d27c5fd2/solr-hadoop-testbase/src/main/java/com/lucidworks/hadoop/utils/SolrCloudClusterSupport.java#L132